Adding empty space between 2 paragraphs
I'm using the following code for a new page of my latex document
\newpage

\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=0.75\linewidth]{Figures/new.jpg}
    \caption{caption}
    \label{fig:newfig}
\end{figure}

\subsection{New subsection}


Paragraph 1


\vspace{10cm}


Paragraph 2


I want to add empty space between para 1 and para 2 but when it compiles I'm getting empty space between figure and sub-heading. How to correct this? Tried forcing \vspace* but then it inserts empty space twice (below and after para 1)

welcome! could you complete your snippet so we can compile it to recreate the problem? you can use e.g. example-image rather than Figures/new.jpg to ensure everyone has what's needed. A figure is a float. as such, it is designed to be moved to what latex considers the 'best' position, so you can't add space around it and expect to get good results. if you don't want it to move, don't use figure.

The default [tbp] is to place the figure at the top of the page with a gap of \textfloatsep=20pt plus 2pt minus 4pt after.  Try using \vfill instead of \vspace between the two paragraphs. assuming 10cm is too big.  Or just use \raggedbottom.
